# virtual model and form_for (or formtastic)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, formtastic

Sometimes we need form without model creation - for example search field or email, where should be send some instructions. What is the best way to create this forms? Can i create virtual model or something like this? I'd like to use formtastic, but not form_tag.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Firstly, Formtastic doesn't need a model in all cases, although it certainly works best and requires less code with a model.

Just like Rails' own built-in `form_for`, you can pass in a symbol instead of an object as the first argument, and Formtastic will build the form and post the params based on the symbol.  Eg:

```
<% semantic_form_for(:session) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

This will make the form values available to your controller as `params[:session]`.

Secondly, a *model* doesn't mean an *ActiveRecord* model.  What I mean is, Formtastic will work with any instance of a class that *quacks* like an ActiveRecord model.

A classic example of this that **many** people are using Authlogic for authentication with Formtastic.  Part of Authlogic is the idea of a UserSession model, which works fine:

Controller:

```
def index
  @user_session = UserSession.new
end
```

Form:

```
<% semantic_form_for(@user_session) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :login %>
  <%= f.input :password %>
<% end %>
```

This will make your form data available in your controller as `params[:user_session]`.

It's *really* not that hard to create a model instance to wrap up the concerns of your model.  Just keep implementing the methods Formtastic is expecting until you get it working!

Comment: I accept your challenge!  Here find a non-ActiveRecord class to "wrap up the concerns of your model."  http://dondoh.tumblr.com/post/4142258573/formtastic-without-activerecord

Answer (score 1):

default_language.rb

```
class DefaultLanguage
  attr_accessor :language_id
end
```

foo_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @default_language = params[:default_language] || Language.find_by_name("English")
  end
```

index.erb

```
<% semantic_form_for @default_language do |form| %>
  <% form.inputs :id => 'default_language' do %>
      <%= form.input :id, 
       :as => :select, 
       :collection => @languages, 
       :required => false, 
       :label => "Primary Language:", 
       :include_blank => false %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

I used AJAX to post the form when the value changed.

Answer (score -1):

Or you simply create a form with form_for and leave the model reference blank.
for example
    `<% form_for "", :url=>some_url do |f| %>`
    `<%= f.text_field "some_attribute" %>`
    `<%= submit_tag "submit" %>`

You can fetch the values by simply saying params[:some_attribute] in your controller.

Comment: I'd say it's because OP is seeking a semantic solution, ideally using Formtastic, and you're suggesting a step backwards.