# How do I write a resource-less form with formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic, formbuilder

I'm having trouble creating the following with formtastic. It's a simple form, but it's not based on a full resource, just a query string param I'd like to send.

```
# index.html.haml
...
= form_tag resources_path, :method => 'get' do |f|
  = label_tag 'filter', 'Filter'
  = text_field_tag(:filter, params[:filter])
  = submit_tag('Go', :name => nil)
```

Formtastic is probably overkill here, but it'd be nice use consistent semantics if possible.

How would you translate the above into formtastic syntax?

Comment: I was looking for the same thing, found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796207/virtual-model-and-form-for-or-formtastic

Answer (score 0):

did you see these RailsCasts:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/184-formtastic-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/185-formtastic-part-2

https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/wiki/4-Formtastic-Options

should be something like this:

```
= semantic_form_for @your_model do |f|
  = f.inputs
  = f.buttons
```

or this:

```
= semantic_form_for @your_model do |f|
  = f.input :filter
  = f.commit_button :label => "Go"
```

Then run `rails g formtastic/stylesheets` and add them to your stylesheets / asset pipeline.
You'll also need to include these extra Formtastic stylesheets in your application layout.

Please check the RailsCasts above for details

Comment: This doesn't answer actually answer my question. Also, I understand what you're getting at, but creating a fake resource and basing the formtastic form on that wouldn't give me the above form. I'd end up with a param resource[:filter] at the very least.

Comment: did you check the RailsCasts about Formtastic? see above

Comment: I have. I may be confused but this still seems wrong. My example is creating a form which points to a resource collection index. The idea is simply to pass a parameter to this index so I can filter my results. 'Filter' is not an attribute of a model, and the form should not be a posting to a given model's url. So this is different from your answer as far as I understand. It seems your assuming I'm using a resource, and that I want to update or create this resource, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid (hence the title).